# How to send image as POST in android studio

Tags: java, android, http

I have to send an image from app to PHP server along with few details.
I have written below code to send the details, but not sure how to send the image. Can anyone help me with this please ?

As you can see, i am using Map to send data to server. But how to add image in this. Any help would be helpful.

```
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "URL", 
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response)
            {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {     
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Response", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> details =  new HashMap<>();
                details.put("id", session.getKey());
                details.put("name", name.toString());
                return details;
            }
        };
strReq.setShouldCache(false);
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
```

Comment: If you can add to map depends on your server. But you did not tell us how your server expect files. Further: what you want is pretty basic and code can be found in examples on the whole internet and many times on this site.

Comment: since i'm sending the data using MAP, the PHP server would expect in POST variables... so the same would be for the image...

Comment: I reccomend switching to retrofit2, multpart file sending is easy there

Comment: volley is cumbersome

Comment: `since i'm sending the data using MAP, the PHP server would expect in POST variables`. Is it? How do you know how the sever wants the file? The only thing you can say "as the server expects the file in a post variable i have to send it in a post variable".

Comment: Because that's how the code is written. Since the POST request contains key value pair, the server is expecting the response as POST variables.

Comment: I see that the code is written that way. But that does not mean that the server wants files in that way. I said that before. But you dont grab the point. You reversed the logic.

Comment: OK.. can you suggest me a solution in which PHP server accepts the request of both image and few variables ??

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert Image Into String. Like this

```
 public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
```

And then you can add image to map like this

/`//Converting Bitmap to String
                String image = getStringImage(bitmap);`

```
            params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
```

Comment: I have the image obtained from URL and converted it to bitmap. So i tried using the above code, but bmp returns null while calling compress method. @taimoor

Answer (score 0):

```
             private  void uploadImage(final String id,  final String name){

                    String tag_string_req = "req_upImage";

                   // pDialog.setMessage("Uploading image......");
                   // showDialog();

                    //converting image to base64 string
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, baos);
                    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                    long imgSize = imageBytes.length;
                    final String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
                   // Log.d(TAG, "Image:" + imageString);


                    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            Log.d(TAG, "Response:" + String.valueOf(response));
                            //hideDialog();
                            try {
                                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                                int success = jObj.getInt("success");
                                if (success == 1) {

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                } else {
                                    // Error occurred in uploading. Get the error
                                    // message
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some error occurred!. Try again ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Uploading Error: " + error.getMessage());
                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Communication Error!.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internal Server Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Error!.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Parse Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                            hideDialog();
                        }


                    }) {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                            // Posting params 
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put("image", imageString);
                            params.put("name", name);
                            params.put("id", id);


                            return params;
                        }

                    };

                    // disabling volley retry policy

                    strReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                            0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));



                    // Adding request to request queue
                    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
                }







                php code



                <?php
        require_once 'db_config.php';
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
        {
         $con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
         $sql ="SELECT image_id FROM table_images ORDER BY image_id ASC";

         $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
         $image_id = 0;
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
         $image_id = $row['image_id'];
         }
         // saving image in a folder 
         $path = "../uploads/images/$image_id.png";

         $actualpath = "http://............./$path";

        $response = array();

        // check for required fields
        if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['image']) && isset($_POST['id']))
         {
          $name = $_POST['name'];
          $image_id = $_POST['id'];
           require_once 'db_Connect.php';
            // connecting to db
            $db = new DB_CONNECT();

            // mysql inserting a new row
            $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_images(name, image, rest_id) VALUES('$name', '$actualpath', '$image_id')");

            // check if row inserted or not
            if ($result) {
                // successfully inserted into database
                $response["success"] = 1;
                $response["message"] = "Image successfully Uploaded.";

                // echoing JSON response
                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                // failed to insert row
                $response["success"] = 0;
                $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

                // echoing JSON response
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        } else {
            // required field is missing
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
        require_once 'db_config.php';
        require_once 'db_Connect.php';
        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            $image = $_POST['image'];
         file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
         /*echo "Successfully Uploaded";*/
         }
         mysqli_close($con);
         }else{
         echo "Error";
         }
        ?>
```